# MySQL question. Struggling to convert text string in correct date format

Tags: mysql, date

I have a column named `strdate` in MySQL database with a table named `data`. The `strdate` column is of type `varchar(100)`
I tried a couple of ways to use the `select` command to get results in a legitimate date format. When I succeed I want to update that column to a proper date type.

I started with this command:
`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(strdate, '%e %M Y, %h %m'), '%H:%i') FROM data where topic = 26801;`

[But that gave me this un-successfull result:](https://imgur.com/221IAjt)

Here are a couple of examples in the `strdate` column which I want to convert:

`7 juni 2016, 22:04`

`19 juli 2011, 20:02`

`9 augustus 2022, 06:07`

I read through this website:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

I assume that I have to write the comma and the colon in a literary way in the query. To summarize: How to compose the query in a way to select the dates in the given example (which are text strings) and convert them to a valid and proper date format. If that goes well I want to use the update command to adjust the type of the `strdate` column and insert the dates as real dates. Any help would be really appriciated.

Comment: 'I assume that I have to write the comma and the colon in a literary way in the query.' true but you didn't in the str_to_date function and %h should be %H there too. Also what country has those month names?

Comment: I'm from the Netherlands so the months are in Dutch. The `strdate` is the column name `STR_TO_DATE(strdate, '%e %M Y, %h %m')`. How can I put comma and colon in that name? Please elaborate. Or should I put the the exact date where I now have strdate? `STR_TO_DATE(7 juni 2016, 22:04, '%e %M Y, %h %m')`. That doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dutch month names can be output by `DATE_FORMAT()`, but unfortunately MySQL does not support the reverse for `STR_TO_DATE()`:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/locale-support.html

> The locale indicated by the `lc_time_names` system variable controls the language used to display day and month names and abbreviations. This variable affects the output from the `DATE_FORMAT()`, `DAYNAME()`, and `MONTHNAME()` functions.
>
> `lc_time_names` does not affect the `STR_TO_DATE()` or `GET_FORMAT()` function.

This feature to parse locale-specific month names was requested in this bug reported in 2012: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64023. You might like to click the "Affects Me" button for that bug, to try to raise the priority of implementing it.

In the meantime, I'm afraid you'll have to parse non-"en_US" month names yourself.

---

Here's a solution showing replacing three month names. For all 12 months, you would need more nested REPLACE() function calls. It's ugly, but it would work.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(strdate, 'juni', 'June'), 'juli', 'July'), 'augustus', 'August'), 
  '%e %M %Y, %H:%i') AS `date`
FROM data
WHERE topic = 26801;
```

Output, tested in MySQL 8.3.0:

```
+---------------------+
| date                |
+---------------------+
| 2016-06-07 22:04:00 |
| 2011-07-19 20:02:00 |
| 2022-08-09 06:07:00 |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: Some `REPLACE` statements may help to just turn the months to english and _then_ use `STR_TO_DATE`

Comment: That is what I concluded when I read Bill's recommendations.
@Bill, thanks for the well documented explanation.  Your query worked 100% for me and   gives me the tools I can work with. I really appreciate it I will mark it as solution.